# Designing textbooks

Tags: art, cartoon

Asalam o alaikum

Recently, I came to know that art is prohibited in islam. I am confused is it art or is it drawing?. Both are very different things. For instance designing something requires art and every creative thing falls in the category of art. For instance making sight appealing brochures or any textbook for educational purposes needs the use of pictures and stuff. So my question is since art is such a huge subject and it involves so many different forms so is it all haram?

Comment: Drawing people are forbidden. Art isn’t.

Comment: Art is almost everywhere, the designs you see on Masjids, etc. Art in general is not haram, but the main things would be faces, and such.